# inertia get clearing my search input type

Tags: vue.js, search, laravel-8, inertiajs

I am working with a search box for my table using laravel inertia and vuejs. I have a problem regarding using the `this.$inertia.get("/member", { term: this.term });` in my method function from vue because it clears my searchbox. When I tried to replace the code above using `this.$inertia.replace(this.route("member.index", { term: this.term }));` it says replace is depreciated.

Here is my full code.

From my search input type:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="table_search"
    class="form-control float-right"
    placeholder="Search"
    v-model="term"
    @keyup="search"
/>
```

And my script:

```
export default {
  props: {
    members: Object,
    filters: Object,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      term: "",
    };
  },

  components: {
    AppLayout,
    Paginator,
  },

  methods: {
    search() {
      //   this.$inertia.replace(this.route("member.index", { term: this.term }));
      this.$inertia.get("/member", { term: this.term });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `{ preserveState:true }` option.

Your code would like something like this:

```
this.$inertia.get("/member", { term: this.term }, { preserveState: true });
```

See the documentation [here](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits#component-state).